# Exporting all events (even past!) from the calendar in Office 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, office365

I have followed [many guides](https://help.zolasuite.com/portal/kb/articles/how-do-i-export-my-calendar-from-microsoft-office-365) that explain to use the "Share calendar" feature in the calendar settings of Office 365. Unfortunately that only creates an .ics file with future events, not including the past ones.

How can I create an ics with ALL the events (even past ones)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the desktop Outlook. Use the File -> Save Calendar menu, click the "More Options..." and specify the desired date range.